# is it possible to have multiple foreign key from the same table?

Tags: mysql, sql

First, i just know sql but not pro at it, so please bear with me

I have a situation where the default condition is (for example) one person only can have one schedule and one schedule only have one person, so i just need to create a `person_id` as `FK` in my `schedule table`. (**1-1 relation**)

However, now a schedule can have more than one person, and one person can have many schedule (**many to many relation**). Is it possible to do this? How to redesign my database?

Comment: Please paste your schema and what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct many to many references between two tables is never a good idea. It is best to stick a separate table inbetween the relationship.
[image]

A sample query would then be along the lines of:

```
select * from Person
join PersonSchedule on PersonSchedule.PersonId= Person.Id
join Schedules on Schedules.Id = PersonSchedule.ScheduleId
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Oh no i will have to change much of the current database. I will wait for other answer before accepting your answer. Too bad i only can upvote once

Comment: I will appreciate if u can tell me how to make a direct many to many relation (the bad idea). The problem is i dont have much time to change the database

Comment: Many to Many are bad. I would not recommend any way to make it work. But, only if you are 'very' stuck, you would have to enter a new person for each schedule that they have. Obviously duplicating your users stops making them unique and that is a world of unhappiness, further down the track. So I certainly don't recommend doing it!!

Comment: @BlazeTama Don't, really. You'll waste more time on it than by doing it correctly, and you'll regret it afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you have it the wrong way around; normally the child table has a reference to its parent. This allows many children to share the same parent.

```
Parent(id, name)
Child(id, parent_id, name)

Parent(1, 'parent')
  - Child(1, 1 'child 1')
  - Child(2, 1 'child 2')
  - Child(3, 1 'child 3')
```

Many to Many is done with a joining table in the middle:

```
Person(id, name)

PersonSchedule(person_id, schedule_id)

Schedule(id, name)

-- you can now specify connections between any schedule and and person
Person(1, 'p1'), Person(2, 'p1')
Schedule(1, 's1'), Schedule(2, 's1')

PersonSchedule(1, 1)
PersonSchedule(1, 2)
PersonSchedule(2, 1)
```

Additionally you'd put data relevant to the relationship on the joining table. Say for example a person might want to be notified about some of their schedules:

```
PersonSchedule(person_id, schedule_id, should_notify)
```

Then you can freely say which people are notified about which schedules (or thinking back the other way, which schedules have people that need to be notified).

Comment: Im sorry, i choose a wrong example. I can understand your answer, but my situation is i need N to N relation. The better example is a person can have multiple schedule, and a schedule can have multiple person. I will update my question ASAP

Comment: Thanks. Sorry i just can accept 1 answer, hope some1 will upvote for your kindness

Answer (score 2):

What you describe is a 1-to-N relation.

In general, 1 parent can have N children.
However, each child can have only 1 parent (well.. not in real life, but I suppose that's what you meant in your example).

They way you model this is:

```
parent(ID, name)
child(ID, name, parent_ID)
```

`child.ID` is a PK (it identifies a child uniquely)

`parent.ID` is a PK (it identifies a parent uniquely)

`child.parent_ID` is a FK that points to `parent.ID`. A FK always points to a PK.

**EDIT:**
From you comment, it seems you wanted an N-to-M relation. Let's again use parents and children, but like in real life: children do have more than 1 parent.
N-to-M relations are modeled using one table in between that links the two.

Example:

```
parent(ID, name) -- ID is PK
parent(1, 'parent1')
parent(2, 'parent2')
parent(3, 'parent3')

child(ID, name) -- ID is PK
child(10, 'child1')
child(11, 'child2')
child(12, 'child3')

-- who is parent of whom?

parent_child(parentID, childID) -- both parentID and childID are FKs
parent_child(1, 10)   -- parent1 is parent of child1
parent_child(2, 10)   -- parent2 is parent of child1
parent_child(2, 11)   -- parent2 is parent of child2

FK: parent_child.parentID -> parent.ID
FK: parent_child.childID -> child.ID
```

One more note. From you question is not clear whether you realise the following:

While setting up the PK and FK constraints for this relations is a very good idea, it is not mandatory and does not affect the modelling of your problem.

One thing is to model your many-to-many scenario with the 3 tables as described above. This will perfectly work.

Another thing is to enforce the PK and FK constraints. This will ensure that you cannot insert inconsistent data by accident (e.g. twice the same person, or a child-parent relationship to a non-existing parent), plus help the query engine provide better efficiency.

Comment: Im sorry, i choose a wrong example. I can understand your answer, but my situation is i need N to N relation. The better example is a  person can have multiple schedule, and a schedule can have multiple person. I will update my question ASAP

Comment: Thanks. Sorry i just can accept 1 answer, hope some1 will upvote for your kindness